# Missing library after upgrading to VisualCpptools 14.32

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++20, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to update my project to use VisualCpptools version 14.32. My project has address sanitizer [ASAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/sanitizers/asan?view=msvc-170) enabled for debug builds. I'm getting the following linker error. Can someone help with it.

```
Build target: src\test\perf
Result: Failed
##[error]LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'stl_asan.lib' [D:\dbs\el\cams\src\test\perf\perf.vcxproj]
##[error]
```

Comment: Regarding LNK1104, I suggest you read this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1104?view=msvc-170) carefully and try to select Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input tab of the project’s properties. There is an Additional Dependencies property, then add quotes to the path. For example, change C:\Program Files\lib\a.lib to "C:\Program Files\lib\a.lib"

Comment: The library stl_asan.lib isn't present in the visualcpptools nuget package "C:\Users\usertest\.nuget\packages\visualcpptools\14.33.31629

Comment: Does stl_asan.lib exist in a certain folder? If so maybe you need to include it in the project manually.

Comment: It exists in my local visual studio 2022 installation. But not in the visualcpptools 14.32 nuget package that is downloaded during build process

Comment: I suggest you try adding the library to your project manually, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-static-library-cpp?view=msvc-170) for details.